# Cannot uninstall apps by command line

Tags: command-line, package-management, dpkg

When trying to uninstall apps by command line, I get the following error:

```
dpkg: error: failed to open package info file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading: 
    No such file or directory
E: Sub-process dpkg --set-selections returned an error code (2)
E: Couldn't record the approved state changes as dpkg selection states
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update`

Comment: every installation or updating must  have sudo in the beginning..

Answer (score 1):

This error was resolved in the comments with :

```
sudo apt update
```

From http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt.8.html

> update (apt-get(8))
>
> ```
>        update is used to download package information from all
>        configured
>        sources. Other commands operate on this data to e.g. perform
>        package upgrades or search in and display details about all
>        packages available for installation.
> ```